# Foreign Object Debris Dataset

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, images, aviation

Is there any dataset available for detection of Foreign Object Debris (FOD) on Runways and Taxiways of Airports?

We have a project in which we want to detect any foreign object on the runway. These objects mostly consist of airplane parts metal/ plastic/ rubber etc.

Is there any images/ dataset available for this purpose?

Comment: there is another data set referred in the paper "FOD Detection using DenseNet with Focal Loss of Object Samples for Airport Runway" but it might not be publically available
Did you manage to find any?

Comment: Thank you. I did not find any data but the project was completed as a prototype by training on available data like Auto parts and wildlife.

Answer (score 0):

found with a [simple internet search](https://www.google.com/search?q=runway%20debris%20dataset), for which there are several results...

one result is this paper

*Foreign object debris material recognition based on convolutional neural networks*

https://doi.org/10.1186/s13640-018-0261-2

provides a download link to the FOD data

> The FOD material dataset can be downloaded from Google Drive.

(136 MB) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UTxZQUipkX6_rC9AoCaweeeeOPrOG1_B

Comment: Thank you for sharing. But this dataset is for the classification of the FOD material type. What I am looking for is the dataset for the localization of foreign object debris present on the runway surface.